# Understanding Nginx try_files and fastcgi_path

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi

I'm trying to convert a very simple .htaccess file to nginx:

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

As I read on Google and many places, try_files should do the trick.  I tried many things but it just doesn't work, looks like nothing is sent to index.php

```
server {

root   /var/www/html/;

location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include         fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The file structure is simple:

```
/var/www/html/folder1/folder2/index.php
/var/www/html/folder1/folder2/.htaccess
```

Nginx error log when requesting the url:

```
013/01/17 14:38:28 [error] 22379#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 1.2.3.4, server: , request: "GET /status/1.0/APP/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "test.com:443"
```

I'm not sure if the problem is a try_files issue or fastcgi_path.

Thank you,

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: It looks more like a php issue (so fatscgi params). As the error comes bck from fastcgi, where php files are notfound. Check the php logs and give us your php pool settings. Especially the chroot settings if any.

Comment: I fixed the issue, it was a stupid error of location /  and root parameter.

Comment: could you post your corrected configuration?

Comment: His `root` should be `/var/www/html` not `/var/www/html/` because URIs start with a forward slash.